# JavaCC: Please give me links to "real" examples

Tags: java, parsing, javacc

I know that there are many examples of JavaCC parsers [here](https://javacc.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=110&expandFolder=110&folderID=109),
but they all do nothing. They just accept a string, or produce parsing errors.

What I need is a few examples of real parsers, which actually do something during parsing. *(Such as building a DOM tree during parsing an XML string).*

Please help! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at EcmaScript.jj that DOJO library maintains over here - http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/trunk/tools/jslinker/src/org/dojo/jsl/parser/EcmaScript.jjt

It parses real javascript and then optimizes it. Read more about what it does out here http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/trunk/tools/jslinker/docs/readme.txt

Answer (score 4):

http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-Tutorial/javacc-tutorial.pdf
http://www.cobase.cs.ucla.edu/projects/coxml/doc/Eric-Master.pdf

Comment: your first tutorial is awesome !!!

Answer (score 2):

The JavaCC website features a grammar repository with grammars for many programming languages (C,C++,VB,etc.).

[Check it out](https://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads/directory/contrib/grammars)

Answer (score 1):

[SourceMeter](http://sourcemeter.sourceforge.net/), as [patched](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=37608&atid=420208), uses JavaCC to derive Java source code metrics.