# How to count comment (single & multiple) lines in java?

Tags: java, comments

I am doing project in Java. In that I am having one part in which, I have to identify the single, multiple comments and total no of comments in the program. I am in need of your guidance to count the no of single line comment, multiple line comment and total no comment lines in java.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Bart Doing so by oneself is nontrivial, because unicode escape sequences (\u000a or \u002f\u002f), String literals ("http: //example.com") and multi-line comments within single-line comments (// test /* test) must be accounted for, and probably some other pitfalls.

Comment: @Christian Semrau, I didn't say s/he should do it by him/herself. I merely asked what s/he already tried. This includes (in case of homework) own code that performs these calculation, or (in case of "professional" work) what tools and/or API's s/he already tried.

Comment: You are right. No offense meant!

Comment: You might look at this related [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732116).

Comment: @Christian, none taken. It's not all that difficult to write a custom lexer for such a task, IMO. Just tedious. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a summary of the line count with regards to comments and code, look at [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/). Point it at a source directory, i.e.:

```
cloc src
```

...and it'll display a summary for you.

CLOC also deals with the corner cases that make it difficult to do this problem yourself - multiline comments, comment looking lines within strings and so on. The following:

```
package test;

public class Main {

/**
 * A javadoc comment.
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("/* This isn't a comment */");
    /* This is a comment */
    //Comment
    System.out.println("//Not comment");
}
//Comment
}
```

CLOC gives 2 blank lines, 7 comment lines, and 7 code lines.

Yes, you could write something yourself in Java but unless this is a specific homework question (in which case it should be tagged as such) why reinvent the wheel? You'd need to deal with lots of corner cases, do lots of tests to make sure it worked, compare it against existing tools etc. and there's really no point in doing that when you've got something that does the job well already.

Comment: Does cloc account for the pitfalls I mentioned in my comment to the question?

Comment: @Christian Semrau yes it does, I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: where is the java implementation for the same.?the link you provided has php implementation

Comment: Cloc does deal with multi-line comment starts within single-line comments (it correctly ignores them). I does not deal with unicode escape sequences, and does not handle block comments within String literals. These are already known limitations, as can be read in the Cloc documentation.

Comment: @Christian Semrau granted, it's not bulletproof. But for most purposes, it's more than good enough, and it would require a significant (most likely infeasible) effort to come up with something better.

Comment: @Christian: For code you have written yourself there should be no unicode escape sequences (for new-lines or `/`). And if we have some code with such in then, we can use native2ascii (after first converting to UTF-8) in the `-reverse` mode to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to an assignment that I did for the same question. Hope this helps.

Note: It is not complete, cos it does not count the case of strings in java(within double quotes) that contain double quotes preceded by escape characters(like "/\"/") as line of code, but rather it counts it as a comment. This still has to be resolved.

http://bit.ly/PDasu9

Here is the explanation :-

```
Note :- This program is not optimized for performance, performance is not an attribute i care about here. I chose not to use Pattern.compile() among many other decisions.

I count the empty lines, comment lines and lines of code separately.

if there is any sentence which has a some tabs or just spaces, they are counted as
empty lines. They match with the regular expression \s*
\s - any whitespace character (\n\t\b)
 * - this means there can be any number of whitespace characters


comment lines are the ones that match any of the following conditions :-
1) have a // outside of a string
2) have a /* some comment */
3) have a /* but the '*/' is not found on the same line

The regular expression for the above can be found inside the code!

Lines of code are the ones that end in ')' , '}' , '{' or ';' (one problem with this approach is that it does not count lines that have code followed by comment as a line of code)

The summary of these three types of lines are provided by this program.
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. You should be explaining how its done directly instead of just linking to a code sample that might not be around when someone else comes to this problem later.

Comment: You should explain the solution here instead of linking to a file.

Comment: thanks for your remarks, i have added an explanation. Pls tell me how I can make the linked file more permanent(is there a website that allows me to do so?), so that you never have to worry about me deleting it(only by accident)?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me . It counts the total number of Single and multiple line comments in a java file.

```
public class CountComment {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            String str;
            BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a.java"));
            LineNumberReader l = new LineNumberReader(f);
            int numberline = 0;
            int count = 0;
            while ((str = l.readLine()) != null) {
                numberline++;
                if (str.startsWith("/*")) {
                    while ((str = l.readLine()) != null) {
                        count++;
                        if (str.endsWith("*/")) {
                            count++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(str.startsWith("//")){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("" + count);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [StreamTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html)

Comment: In order to reliably identify comments, one would need to parse some parts of the language as well: Don't count comments within String literals, ignore starts of multi-line comments within single-line comments and vice versa, handle unicode escape sequences like \u000a which end a single-line comment.

Answer (score 0):

In Java You have two type of comments:

// - Line comment

/* */ - Block comment.

Basing on this you can make simple assumptions:

> - if in line exist "//" then this line has at le one comment.
> - if in line exist "/*" a comment block has been opened.
> - if comment block is open(found) search for closing tag "*/".

So Your task is to check each line in file for those assumptions.

Comment: Your assumptions must be handled with care: 1) `String s = "//";` has no comment, 2) The line `// single /* line` does not start a block comment, 3) the sequence `*\u002f` ends a block comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Below is the working code 

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CountComment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line="";
        int count=0;
        try {
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./src/numbers/comment.txt"));
                while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    if(line.startsWith("//"))
                        count++;
                    if(line.startsWith("/*"))
                    {
                        count++;
                        while(!(line=br.readLine()).endsWith("'*\'"))
                        {
                        count++;
                        break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                br.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
             catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        System.out.println("count="+count);
        } 


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For one of my class assignments I wrote a simple java code which does this task.
https://github.com/chetanpawar0989/CommentAnalysis

I created this file before but I recently added to github.
This program runs on one file and line by line. It takes one imput parameter on runtime *filename.java*

For example, to run this program: `java CommentAnalysis filename.java`

It counts single line (//) as well multi-line comments (/* ... */).

I tried to cover different comment scenarios as mentioned in [this file](https://github.com/chetanpawar0989/CommentAnalysis/blob/master/comment%20scenarios.txt).

I have also written my assumptions about my implementation in readme, but they should not be much difficult to change as per individual requirements. Please check it out and let me know if I am missing any comment scenario here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it works very well. With the code below, you will have to check each line:

```
                if (isEmpty(s) || s.IndexOf("\"//\"") != -1 || s.IndexOf("\"/*\"") != -1|| s.IndexOf("\"*/\"") != -1) continue;
                if (s.IndexOf("/*") != -1) checkCML = true;
                if (s.IndexOf("*/") != -1) checkCML = false;

                if (s.IndexOf("/*") != -1 && s.IndexOf("*/") != -1) ++commentLine;

                if (s.IndexOf("//") != -1 || checkCML) ++commentLine;
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be:

```
public int countCommentLines(File file) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    int comments = 0;
    String line;
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.trim();
        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.startsWith("//")) {
            //single line
            comments++;
        } else if (line.startsWith("/*")) {
            /* multiline
             * like this
             *  */
            comments++;
            while (!line.endsWith("*/")) {
                line = input.readLine().trim();
                comments++;
            }
        } else if (line.contains("/*")) { /* comments
        like this
        be careful with /* haha
        */
            Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<Character>();
            boolean hasStartOfComment = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - 1; ++i) {
                if (stack.isEmpty() && line.charAt(i) == '/' && line.charAt(i + 1) == '*') {
                    // Yes this is the start of a block comment
                    hasStartOfComment = true;
                    break;
                } else if (line.charAt(i) == '\\'
                        && line.charAt(i + 1) == '\"' || line.charAt(i + 1) == '\'') {
                    // Well, it's escaped character
                    i++;
                    continue;
                } else if (line.charAt(i) == '\'' || line.charAt(i) == '\"') {
                    if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == line.charAt(i)) {
                        stack.pop();
                    } else {
                        stack.push(line.charAt(i));
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (!hasStartOfComment) {
                continue;
            }

            while (!line.endsWith("*/")) {
                line = input.readLine().trim();
                comments++;
            }
        }
    }
    return comments;
}
```